# BETWEEN/IN errors in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, operators

I'm having some trouble understanding why PostgreSQL gives me the SQL error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 4: WHERE public.prospect.rating IN (1,2);
                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You 
might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 279
```

Here is the line of code I am using:

```
SELECT public.people.organization, public.people.firstname, 
public.people.lastname, 
public.people.linkedinurl, public.people.orgcrunchbaseurl
FROM public.prospect LEFT JOIN public.people ON 
public.prospect.organization = public.people.organization
WHERE public.prospect.rating BETWEEN 1 and 2;
```

The issue I have is in the last line. I have also tried:

```
WHERE public.prospect.rating IN (1,2);
```

I'm trying to narrow the search to items that only have a 1 or 2 rating.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use table aliases?

```
SELECT p.organization, p.firstname, p.lastname, p.linkedinurl, p.orgcrunchbaseurl
FROM public.prospect pr LEFT JOIN
     public.people p
     ON pr.organization = p.organization
WHERE pr.rating BETWEEN 1 and 2;
```

Comment: I figured out the problem! When i initially set up the table, I set all the columns data type to VARCHAR and totally forgot that these boolean operators would only work on numbers. I altered the data type and the original code worked!